# Why pm2 is fine, but pm2 logs is not?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using pm2 to keep tracking of what I do on backend with NodeJS. Until yesterday it all worked perfectly fine, but today, even if pm2 server is working fine (i can start the project server and i can navigate), pm2 logs just stopped for no reasons.

[image]

Here you can see the version I'm using (i already updated PM2 both on project and local as i find in other answers). 
I usually use the command

```
pm2 start process.json
pm2 restart 0 --watch
pm2 restart 0
```

And in other prompt instance, for the logs i use

```
pm2 logs
```

For some reason PM2 is just tailgating the last 15 lines but it doesn't work real time like it used to do

[image]

I didn't find this exact problem on other questions (only questions about pm2 not working at all, but not about pm2 working half way). Any suggestions?

Comment: what shows `pm2 logs --lines 1000` ?

Comment: It just tailgates last 1000 lines but it doesn't work real time like it used to do

Comment: So there are new logs but the watch mode is not working? What version did you install?

Comment: Yes correct. I'm using the 4.5.0 version. I updated this morning because in other questions they said it could be usefull to update. It worked fine until yesterday (with previous version)

Comment: Ok i managed to resolve that, i will write that at the end of the question

Comment: You may answer your own question :+1:

Comment: Yes i did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the version of node and pm2 were the source of the problem. I used this command to run pm2 using the node version explicitly

```
pm2 start process.json --interpreter=/home/ken/.nvm/v10.15.1/bin/node
```

This way you force pm2 to use settings for the version of node you've installed in your machine. Now both server and logs works fine.